# Laravel - Query two Models with special conditions

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two two table:

1. department (Department)

   id,
   dept_code and
   dept_point
2. designation (Designation)

   id,
   dept_code,
   designation_point and
   created_at

I want to select dept_code, designation_point, created_at from designation.  The query should loop through the designation table and use these conditions.

**Conditions**

1. select all   dept_code, designation_point and created_at from designation where dept_code is not equal to 101 and 102
2. If dept_code = 101 or dept_code = 101, in designation, it should select matching dept_code, designation_point and created_at from designation using these conditions:

> department.dept_code = designation.dept_code
>
> department.dept_point = designation.designation_point

This is the code I have already

Controller

```
        $designations = DB::table('designation as g')
    ->select(
       'g.dept_code', 
       'g.designation_point',
       DB::raw("DATE(created_at) as created_date")
  )
 ->orderByRaw('g.created_at DESC')
            ->get();
```

View

```
        @foreach($designations as $key => $designation)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
            <td>{{ $designation->dept_code }}</td>               
            <td>{{ $designation->designation_point }}</td>
            <td>{{ $designation->created_date }}</td>
        </tr>          
    @endforeach
```

How do I complete the code in the Controller

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean with your second condition. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Using Builder

```php
$designations = DB::table('designations')
  ->select('dept_code', 'designation_point', 'created_at')
  # Condition 1
  ->whereNotIn('dept_code', [101, 102])
  ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
  ->get();
```

Using Eloquent

```php
$designations = App\Designation::select('dept_code', 'designation_point', 'created_at')
  # Condition 1
  ->whereNotIn('dept_code', [101, 102])
  ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
  ->get();
```